# Swing - Drop down Panel

Tags: java, awt, jogl

I am working on Java Swing, making an UI. I have a Panel (Panel 1) with information, and I want to create a dropdown menu, but not like de comboBox. Is hard to explain.

I see the panel, and in the bottom, I have a button. When I press this button, I want to make appear another panel (transparent) on Panel 1.

I dont know how can I do that.I wait for yoir help, if I have explained it well.

I dont want the typical dropdown list, is like a dropdown panel.

EDIT: for example, in the main page of google, when you hit a button above, appears a new menu, but not a list.  I see that is not a good example, i am searching another better example for it.

EDIT 2: I need that the thing that appear when I press the button will be a Panel, because I need to add some JOGL on it.

Comment: What about a JPopupMenu ? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleexampleofJPopupMenu.htm

Comment: Nope, it is not useful because I need a Panel to put more things in it with  JOGL. Edit question for this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant _Popup_, see : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Popup.html

Comment: If you need a heavy weight component, because you're using JOGL, then you shouldn't mark the question as `Swing` and `JPanel` as they will not help you.  Also, you shouldn't be mixing heavy and light weight components ;)

Comment: I think yes, because I am using Swing to prepare all the window structure, and then, in a JPanel, I add JOGL code using that Panel

Comment: You can use a javax.swing.JInternalFrame, you can drive it transparent and show it above your GUI. You can use a com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel in this internal frame and/or in the GUI below. I don't advise you to use AWT and the heavyweight com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PopupFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/PopupFactory.html) for this .

```
PopupFactory factory = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance();
Popup popup = factory.getPopup(myButton, myPanel, x, y);
popup.show();
```

x and y are screen coordinates.

Comment: I dont understand you